# How to split multiline stdin input in r?

Tags: r, string, input, file-io, stdin

I am working in R and am supposed to split the `stdin` inputs using `space` and `newline` characters. However, when I take the input as a string from stdin using the following code:

```
f <- file("stdin")
open(f)

sampleInput <- readLines(f)
```

with the following values in `stdin`:

```
1 2
3 4 4
```

`print(sampleInput)` returns the following output and I am not sure how to split it.

```
[1] "1 2"   "3 4 4"
```

Can someone suggest a way to split this input using space and newline characters (just like `split()` works in python) as follows?

```
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "4"
```

Comment: You can try `sampleInput <- unlist(strsplit(readLines(f), " "), FALSE, FALSE)`. This further splits each string by `" "` and flattens the list into a vector.

Comment: Just a little modification to accommodate next line characters 
`sampleInput <- readLines(f)
sampleInput <- gsub(", "," ",toString(sampleInput))
sampleInput <- unlist(strsplit(sampleInput, " "), FALSE, FALSE)`